# Control Visibility (Viewport-Render) of All Modifier at once

Tags: modifiers, visibility

I have a Collection, in this collection I have Multiple Mesh with each multiple Modifier.
I would like to control the visibility in Viewport and Render of all Modifiers with same name at once.

I have tried different stuff, but I can't find the best way to toggle visibility...

Thanks

Comment: i think you could do that by a python script pretty quick, if you have a bit experience of python + Blender API. Shouldn't be too hard. And then you can turn that into an add-on. Tbh i am too lazy to do that for you because i think it is a very special case and i don't think that a lot of people would use that. Maybe you should better ask on Blenderartists.org for "volunteer work".

Comment: I had the thought that such a window to view all modifiers at once is indeed currently missing, years ago. To my knowledge there is no out of the box solution available right now, if you are not looking for a "write a python script in that case" kind of answer. Correct me if I am wrong.